# Steam not work in Debian 7 - Illegal instruction

Tags: linux, debian, steam, deb

I don't know what can I do to make this work, help is needed.

I installed steam from Debian repos - by synaptic, all I have is "not found":

```
Illegal instruction
/usr/games/steam: 16: /usr/games/steam: /home/pmache/.steam/steam.sh: not found
```

Inspecting steam folder, I discover that steam folder is almost empty

```
$ ls ~/.steam
ubuntu12_32
```

I have nvidia drivers latest for my GPU. Any help? Reinstallation doesn't help the problem.

Installing package from Github also doesn't work -

```
segmentation fault
```

Comment: id you follow the isntructions here? https://wiki.debian.org/Steam

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Installing package from GitHub won't work because you probably have 32bit CPU. Also, I would not use Debian 7, it's really outdated version...